# How to programatically print a user´s picture? This code won´t work

Tags: php, variables, drupal-7

I’ve tried this so far in a Drupal 7 installation:

```
<?php print $user_picture; ?>
<?php print $user->picture ?>
<?php print $node->picture ?>
```

None of these snippets will get me the picture printed on the page.

I’m using Devel’s module, so I tried to get it to give me some hints. This is all I get:

```
picture (String, 1 characters ) 0
$...->picture
```

I’ve read that to print a variable you just print or echo it (`echo $var1` for example). So why won’t this work? I’m adding this snippet inside my `node.tpl.php` template.

Any thoughts on this? Thank you for your insight!!

**Update:** This is the result of `var_dump($user_picture)`:

```
string(0) ""
```

Comment: What is picture? Filepath? Binary data?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? an `<img>` tag? raw .jpg/png/gif bytes?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to guess the name of the variable you need - I'm not sure that's an effective strategy. What do the docs say the approach should be?

Comment: $user_picture is the variable. The other two are my own guesses. And that variable should output the picture. I´m adding to the question the results of var_dump() to clarify.

Comment: you probably want to do something like [*this*](http://drupal.org/node/254940#user-picture)

Comment: Thanks alfasin! That´s exactly what I want to do! But then again, $user_picture; won´t output anything (the user has a custom picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails:

```
global $user;
$image = theme('user_picture', array('account' => $user));
print $image;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Clive! Anyway, I get an error: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /includes/theme.inc on line 1054". Looking for that line:   if (isset($variables['#theme']) || isset($variables['#theme_wrappers'])) {
    $element = $variables;
    $variables = array();
    if (isset($info['variables'])) {
      foreach (array_keys($info['variables']) as $name) {
        if (isset($element["#$name"])) {
          $variables[$name] = $element["#$name"];
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Sorry it should be `$image = theme('user_picture', array('account' => $user));`